# No matching constructor for initialization of 'stringstream'

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and I'm passing a `std:stringstream` straight to another method like below:

```
static void copy(byte_array src, int end, stringstream sb) {
    copy(src, 0, end, sb);
}
```

And it gives me:

> no matching constructor for initialization of 'stringstream' (aka 'basic_stringstream<char>')

Why do I need a constructor there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass streams by value, they do not include copy constructors. You should pass them by reference:

```
static void copy(byte_array src, int end, stringstream& sb) {
    copy(src, 0, end, sb);
}
```

[edit]

examples on how you can pass your stream to function in order to modify it:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84e78bdf99575eb4

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>

// By reference
static void copy1(const char* src, int end, std::stringstream& sb) {
    std::copy(src, src + end, std::ostream_iterator<char>(sb));
}

// By pointer
static void copy2(const char* src, int end, std::stringstream* sb) {
    std::copy(src, src + end, std::ostream_iterator<char>(*sb));
}

// By value, but uses move semantics
static std::stringstream copy3(const char* src, int end, std::stringstream sb) {
    std::copy(src, src + end, std::ostream_iterator<char>(sb));
    return sb;
}

// Actually also by reference but using std::ref
template<typename S>
static void copy4(const char* src, int end, S sb) {
    std::copy(src, src + end, std::ostream_iterator<char>(sb));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char arr[3] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
    {
    std::stringstream s;    
    copy1(arr, 3, s);
    std::cout << s.str() << std::endl;
    }

    {
    std::stringstream s;
    copy2(arr, 3, &s);
    std::cout << s.str() << std::endl;
    }

    {
    std::stringstream s;
    s = copy3(arr, 3, std::move(s));
    std::cout << s.str() << std::endl;
    }

    {
    std::stringstream s;
    copy4(arr, 3, std::ref(s));
    std::cout << s.str() << std::endl;
    }    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So i cannot pass a stringstream to a method unless I'm passing by reference, because stringstream are non-copiable, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, in your case - if you want a function which modifies stream it makes sense to pass it by reference.

Comment: Duh! Passing by value won't do anything. I have to remember that C++, different than Java, always pass by VALUE, never by reference. So whenever I pass an object to a method that wants to modify that object I need to pass by reference otherwise it is worthless.

Comment: There are other way also, I have included few examples

Comment: Thanks! And just so I understand: when you pass a `std::vector` by value you are actually making a SHALLOW COPY of the object, so when you modify the vector inside the method the outside world will see it because the contents of the vector are in the heap? Or am I mistaken here and I also have to pass `std::vector` by reference to a modifying method !? How do I know that? Documentation?

Comment: Sorry, forget what I said above. It does a deep copy :( So I also need to pass it by reference, correct? In case of arrays, isn't it better to always pass by reference so you are not copying it around?

Comment: vector passed by value will be copied, with all its values, so yes - you would have to pass it by reference. In case as in your question passing by referencje is recomended, on other uses you may rely on move semantics but that is a broad topic

Comment: One last question: If I'm passing a string or any object as READ-ONLY, why would I ever want to copy it? Never? Better to pass const reference and avoid the copying, right? Trying to guess: for security because you can still get the pointer from `const string&` and modify its contents if you really want to?

Comment: Yes, reference to const string should be fine in such case. You can get only pointer to const string which you cannot modify.

Comment: I have just figured out here that if you cast to (char *) you can modify it freely O.o. It is just a compiler trick. But I think it is fine, because you are the one coding the method. I guess if I give my string to some third party API I should expect them to take it by VALUE, not by reference. If they take it by reference they can mess up with me :)

Answer (score 3):

Becasue passing by value requires a copy-constructor, and stream objects are specifically made non-copy-constructible. You can pass the stream by reference or move it.